# TikZ UML diagram special character problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, characters, pgf-umlcd

I'm trying to create an UML diagram using TikZ and pgf-umlcd, unfortunately I seem to have some kind of special character problem and was not able to figure out how to escape them right, an example would be:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{package}{Test}
        \begin{interface}[text width=7cm]{TestInterface}{0,0}
            \operation{testOperation(a : Map<String, Integer>>) : Boolean}
        \end{interface}
    \end{package}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Unfortunately the greater than and less than characters are not printed in a PDF file like they should be instead some "character mess" is printed. What's wrong?

Answer (score 10):

Just add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` for direct support of the < and > character. To avoid a >> ligature, you youd insert `{}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{package}{Test}
        \begin{interface}[text width=7cm]{TestInterface}{0,0}
            \operation{testOperation(a : Map<String, Integer>{}>) : Boolean}
        \end{interface}
    \end{package}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I redefined << and >> symbols not using `\guillemotleft` and `\guillemotright`, so that the new release of tikz-uml, coming soon, does not depend anymore on `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`